# How can I set a value using JSON.parse if the value I am parsing may be null?

Tags: javascript

In my Javascript I am trying to set the value of a variable like this:

```
var admin = data.adminJSON || JSON.parse(data.adminJSON);
```

The problem I have is that if the value of `data.adminJSON` is null then this gives me an error.

How can I make it so that admin is null if `data.adminJSON === null` and admin is the parsed value if it's not null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
var admin = data.adminJSON && JSON.parse(data.adminJSON);
```

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

---

Another solution would be to use the ternary operator:

```
var admin = data.adminJSON === null ? null : JSON.parse(data.adminJSON);
```

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: So true && a value is equal to value ?

Comment: You'll find more details on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators